# How does new rate limit for Instagram work?

Tags: instagram

From [this post](http://developers.instagram.com/post/87743402071/new-tools-and-rate-limits-for-post-endpoints), it appears that current javascript/mobile clients will have a lower rate limit compare to server app:

> Unsigned Calls (per OAuth token):
>
> POST /media/media-id/likes:  30/hour
>   POST /media/media-id/comments:  15/hour
>   POST /users/user-id/relationships:  20/hour
>
> Signed Calls (per OAuth token):
>
> POST /media/media-id/likes:  100/hour
>   POST /media/media-id/comments:  50/hour
>   POST /users/user-id/relationships:  60/hour

Is there a technical problem if we sign our request with X-Insta-Forwarded-For using our javascript/mobile app, because the new limit for unsigned calls is way too low for our usage now. I'd appreciate any reply from Instagram employees.

Comment: Why you write here for instagram employees? It's stack overflow, not instagram

Comment: http://instagram.com/developer/support/ - The Stack Overflow community is a great place to ask API related questions or if you need help with your code. Make sure to tag your questions with the Instagram tag to get fast answers from other fellow developers and members of the Instagram team.

Comment: @Justinas - maybe because the Instagram Developer Support page says "The Stack Overflow community is a great place to ask API related questions"?

Comment: Can you please tell me that How to make the Signed Call for the Instagram. ? Can It be done from the mobile side rather than server call ?